# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/main.dart:4:10: Error: Method not found: 'MateriaLApp'.
runApp(MateriaLApp(
^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It should be `MaterialApp(...)` and not `MateriaLApp(...)`.

`MateriaLApp` is a Widget from the material package.